# I can't download to my sd card from a Windows Store

Tags: 8.1

I use a Lumia 530.
I can't download to my sd card from the windows store but I can download pictures from websites. Each time I change my storage preference to phone, the download will work but not on sd card. It wasn't like this before.

I have formatted the sd card so many times but the problem still remain. I also bought another sd card, is still the same story.

Please help!!! I have less than 200mb left on my phone memory.

Thank you.

Rotimi.

Comment: Can you share a Storage Sense screen shot?

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: this is not a duplicate and the answers provided in link do not work, This seems to be an issue with lumia 530 and most recent microsoft update,

Comment: no errors, just an unchanging pending screen

Comment: @Craicerjack Sorry but the OP even didn't bother to come back answer our question to help. It's unlikely this particular Question can be saved. If you can elaborate more on this regard and make a clear statement that your question is not the same as the one quoted here please do a new Question.